# Yii2: Filter query by pivot table when using `joinWith()`

Tags: yii2, yii2-active-records

Take the following sample `Cart` model. It has a `CartItem` "pivot record/table" which links it to `Item`.

```php
class Cart extends ActiveRecord {

    public function getCartItems() {
        return $this
            ->hasMany(CartItem::class, ['cart_id' => 'id'])
            ->inverseOf('cart');
    }

    public function getItems($callback = null) {
        return $this
            ->hasMany(Item::class, ['item_id' => 'id'])
            ->via('cartItems', $callback);
    }

}
```

(Example #1) At this point I would be able to filter either by `Item`'s activequery or `CartItem`'s query like so:

```php
$booksAddedToCartSinceYesterday = $cart
    ->getItems(function($cartItemQuery) {
        $cartItemQuery->andWhere('cartItem.created_at > NOW()');
    })
    ->andWhere(['item.category' => 'books']);
```

(Example #2) But how do I accomplish the same when I use the static `find()` method in combination with `joinWith()`? In the following example I am only able to filet by `Item`'s ActiveQuery, but I no longer have any reference to the `CartItem`'s ActiveQuery object:

```php
$booksAddedToCartSinceYesterday = Cart::find()
    ->andWhere(['cart.user_id' => $some_user_id])
    ->joinWith([
        'items' => function($itemQuery) {
            $itemQuery->andWhere(['item.category' => 'books']);
        },
    ]);
```

How do I modify the code above so that I am able to filter `CartItem` junction table records like I did in my example #1? How do I access the junction ActiveQuery object so that I can call `$cartItemQuery->andWhere('cartItem.created_at > NOW()');`?

Comment: I think the problem lies on table names. What is the output for `$query->createCommand()->getRawSql()` on both those cases?

Answer (score 0):

you can pass any variable value in **anonymous function** with **use keyword** link below

make your magic code here for filter or any

```
->joinWith([
    'items' => function($itemQuery) use ($var1,$var2){
        $itemQuery->andWhere(['item.category' => 'books']);
        $itemQuery->andWhere(['some_condition' => $var1]); <<<---------
    },
]);
```

Comment: It is not filtering by junction table, it filters only by related model table